# C using a file as an argument

Tags: c, input, command-line-arguments

The problem I am having is that whenever I run the code I get the Null value for myfile before I even get to pass the file name as the argument into the program and i'm not sure why any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* myFile; // file pointer
    myFile = fopen(argv[1] , "r"); //open file
    if(myFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't Open FIle.\n"); // if file doesn't exist then exit
        exit(0);
    }

    int A[10000]={0};
    int B[10000]={0};
    double C[10000]={0};
    int N,M;
    int i=0;

    fscanf (myFile, "%d", &N); //input N from file
    printf("%d\n",N);
    if(N>100)
    {
        exit(0); // if N>100 then exit
    }
    while (!feof (myFile)) // loop until file pointer reaches to the end of file
    {
        fscanf (myFile, "%d", &A[i]); //input source
        fscanf (myFile, "%d", &B[i]); // input destination
        fscanf (myFile, "%lf", &C[i]); // input time
        i++;
    }
    fclose (myFile); //close file

    M=i; // number of lines = M

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if(A[i]==0) //end of output
            break;
        else
        {
            printf("%d %d %lf:\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]); //print source, destination and time
            if(A[i]>=1&&A[i]<=N)
            {
                if(B[i]>=1&&B[i]<=N)
                {
                    if(A[i]==B[i])
                    {
                        printf("Error:Source city is the same as destination city.\n"); //same source and destination error:condition
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(C[i]<0)
                        {
                            printf("Error:Invalid Time.\n"); //invalid time
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Error: Invalid destination city.\n"); //invalid destination condition
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error: Invalid source city.\n"); //invalid source condition
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without indentation it's not possible to read your code, and consequently impossible to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "before I even get to pass the file name as the argument into the program" ? You should pass the argument when you run the program: myprogram.exe filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass a file name as an argument to the program, the contents of `argv[1]` are undefined.

Since anything could be there in `argv[1]` when the program attempts to open the file, the most probable thing is that there is no file with that name, and hence `fopen()` returns `NULL`.

You should not try to access command line arguments without checking that they were supplied, for that check `argc`, if you just expect 1 argument, then a simple check would be

```
char filename[256]; /* the size should be reasonable
                     * can be PATH_MAX or MAX_PATH,
                     * depending on whether it's Windows
                     * or not
                     */
if (argc < 2)
 {
    size_t length;

    fprintf(stdout, "Error: %s program expects one argument\n", argv[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "Please input the file name: ");
    if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin) == NULL)
     {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: unexpected error\n");
        return -1;
     }
    length = strlen(filename);
    if (length == 0)
     {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error: the provided file name is invalid.\n");
        return -1;
     }
    if (filename[length - 1] == '\n')
        filename[length - 1] = 0;
 }
else
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

Comment: NEVER work on the assumption that all arguments are supplied. The most useful, in general, part of this answer, seems to be the recommendation to ALWAYS check for argument count.

Comment: @nestedloop NO assumption is good when it comes to writing safe code.

Comment: So how would I prompt the user to input a file name

Comment: Thanks for the help just picked up C a few days ago so still new